# String Uses In OOP | Duplicates Letter That Shouldnt Been Duplicate

Tags: string, oop

Im trying OOP JavaScript, my problem is the next one:

```
String message = Keyboard.StringReader("Introduce the message to codificate: ");

String key = Keyboard.StringReader("Introduce the key code: ");

Encryptation sequence_1 = new Encryptation(message,key);
```

***When I put in a String with a space, there's no problem. It execute the next code:***

```
//This is the constructor, who takes the space
public Encryptation(String p, String o){

    this.message = p;
    this.keycode = o;

}
```

//And here is the problem: when I roam the String and it takes place where the space is, the programm changes it into the letter before the space. If *this.message* was "AAA AAA", *messageToken()* returns "AAAAAAA". So I dont know how to fix this. Any help?

```
public char messageToken(){

    int i = 0
    i++;

    return this.message.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look anything like JavaScript. Are you sure you know what programming language you're using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your messagtoken is returning always charAt(1)